# Are there any abilities in Dnd 5e where a clause effects the entire ability?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats

Preamble to the question:

Okay, was talkin' with a bit of friends about a character idea of a thief rogue with the healer feat due to the fast hands feature:

> Fast Hands
> Starting at 3rd level, you can use the bonus action granted by your Cunning Action to make a Dexterity (Sleight of Hand) check, use your thieves’ tools to disarm a trap or open a lock, or take the Use an Object action.

And the first bullet point of the healer feat:

> When you use a healer's kit to stabilize a dying creature, that creature also regains 1 hit point.

Initially, I thought it was a neat concept, providing a bonus action heal for 1 hit point. However, a friend of mine pointed out that this might not work due to the second clause of the healer feat, specifically the part highlighted in bold:

> As an action. you can spend one use of a healer's kit to tend to a creature and restore 1d6 + 4 hit points to it, plus additional hit points equal to the creature's maximum number of Hit Dice. The creature can't regain hit points from **this feat** again until it finishes a short or long rest.

Their argument was that because it mentions "this feat" instead of "in this way," the second clause of the feat could potentially impact the entire feat.

However, in my experience, I've never come across an ability in any game where a clause of an ability affects the entire ability without being directly included in the ability's description. For instance, a possible rephrasing could be:

> Fake Healer You are an able physician, allowing you to mend wounds
> quickly and get your allies back in the fight. You gain the following
> benefits:
>
> -When you use a healer's kit to stabilize a dying creature, that creature also regains 1 hit point.
>
> -As an action. you can spend one use of a healer's kit to tend to a creature and restore 1d6 + 4 hit points to it, plus additional hit
> points equal to the creature's maximum number of Hit Dice.
>
> The creature can't regain hit points from this feat again until it
> finishes a short or long rest.

This formulation would make more sense if the feat was intended to work that way.

So, the tl;dr of the question is:

If this is accurate, are there any other abilities/feats/items that also follow this precedent, or perhaps some that might contradict it?

Comment: I have closed this as a duplicate of the linked question.  Thanks @Deeps.  While this question adds the 'Fast Hands' motivation, the use of that ability does not seem material to the answer.  Laz zlo, please read the linked question, and if you feel it is not the same as yours, please explain why so that this question can be re-opened.

Comment: I’ve voted to leave closed for now, I don’t understand what you’re asking at all.

Answer (score 0):

The wording of it is a bit weird (feels like an editing issue to me), but because "The creature can't regain hit points from this feat again" is part of the second bullet point ("As an action, you can spend one use"), I would think the limitation should apply only to the second bullet point, not to the feat as a whole.

As a DM I would certainly rule that only the big heal counts, not the 1 HP on a Stabilize.

Comment: I don't see any answers at the linked question offering an example of when a bullet point clearly applies internally but not to other bullet point.  If you could describe an example of that, I think your answer would be better than either that are there.